# VSE crop video without stretching

Tags: video-sequence-editor, dimensions

I am cropping a video sequence by checking the "crop" box and taking off, say, 200 pixels on both sides. Unfortunately, the resulting video is stretched to accommodate the initial aspect ratio.

How do I avoid this stretching? I just need to crop the video and then "Drop-over" another image or video.

Comment: Did you use Image Offset as well? It might change your Images size, so that you'd have to scale it again, but prevent the stretching.

Comment: @Samoth I am using the X/Y offset change for the video to move it to the corner, but want the background image fullscreen.

Answer (score 5):

I use the [VSE transform addon](https://github.com/kgeogeo/VSE_Transform_Tools) when you have added your strip press T and it'll be scaled with the correct aspect ratio, then G, R, S grab rotate scale the strip. see the docs for more options

Comment: How to install the addon? The readme file does not seem to specify.

Comment: like any other... download the py, in user pref/addon tab click install from file and select that file (VSE_Transform_Tool.py) then click on the checkbox to activate. Save user pref to make it permanent

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a Transform Effect strip
2. Set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Over*
3. Use the *Position* slider to control the right hand cropping
4. Tick *Image Offset* under *Strip Input*
5. Use *X* to control the left hand cropping

Similarly for the Y axis

[image: How to crop video in blender]